# Modelagem tabela banco de dados

Tags: sql, sql-server, modelagem

Estou criando uma banco de dados que armazena uma nota fiscal eletrônica - "NFe" recebida.

Dentro dos itens de uma nota fiscal sempre estão vinculados os impostos.

Exemplo da tabela `tblProdNFe_Entrada` com a tabela `tblICMS00NFe_Entrada`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou criando o banco exatamente como o objeto gerado pela deserialização que estou fazendo com o seguinte código:

```
    T LoadFromXMLString<T>(string xmlText)
    {
        var stringReader = new System.IO.StringReader(xmlText);
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        return (T)serializer.Deserialize(stringReader);
    }
```

Existem grupos de ICMS, por exemplo: ICMS00, ICMS10, ICMS30 e assim por diante.

Cada grupo se torna um objeto durante a deserialização.

Minha duvida é se devo criar as tabelas no banco exatamente como os objetos ou se devo criar uma tabela que contenha todos os campos de todos os grupos.

Por exemplo uma tabela `tblICMSGeral` que contenha armazene todos os grupos, ou uma tabela para cada grupo: `tblICMS00NFe_Entrada` , `tblICMS10NFe_Entrada` , `tblICMS20NFe_Entrada` e assim por diante.

Qual a melhor forma?

Comment: Aí depende, os tipos de ICMS possuem os mesmos atributos? Se sim, aconselho a criar somente uma tabela que armazene todos e criei um campo adicional para verificar o tipo de ICMS, do contrário crie uma tabela para cada, coloque os campos que se comuns a eles em uma e as informações que são diferentes em outra para não haver redundância de acordo com a 1ª Forma Normal.

Comment: @NayronMorais, neste caso específico não posso deixar 100 % normalizado, o governo muda as regras com muita frequência. Por exemplo o campo `pICMS` que no caso é o percentual de icms, ele tem que ficar como está na NFe, caso seja uma chave estrangeira e eu alterasse ela, todas as notas já gravadas seriam alteradas, coisa que não pode ocorrer, pois tenho de deixar no banco exatamente como está na NFe. Não sei como resolver isto.

Comment: Você poderia acrescentar a normalização somente para os novos dados, daí criaria procedures distintas para verificar nas duas tabelas e aos poucos ir migrando os dados antigos, pois é bom resolver o problema agora, do contrário só irá aumentar junto de seu trabalho.

Comment: Robss70, a resposta dada foi boa? Ou tem outra dúvida ainda?

Answer (score 1):

Crie uma tabela que contenha todos os campos de todos os grupos, perceba que existe a ICMS90 com todos os campos, que é justamente caso exista alguma excessão. Então crie a sua tabela de imposto do ICMS baseada no Grupo ICMS90.